# Discrete topology and Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

What is the difference? If I understand well, both have only points that are isolated, i.e. each point has a neighbourhood that doesn't intersect with a neighbourhood from other points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every discrete space is Hausdorff, but there are many, many Hausdorff spaces that are not discrete, including the very familiar $\Bbb R$. You appear to have misunderstood the Hausdorff property. It does *not* imply that all points are isolated; it just says that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct points, they have disjoint open nbhds. In $\Bbb R$, for instance, suppose that $x\ne y$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $x<y$. Let $a$ be any real number between $x$ and $y$; then $(x-1,a)$ and $(a,y+1)$ are disjoint open nbhds of $x$ and $y$, respectively, but no point of $\Bbb R$ is isolated.

One *can* prove that a *finite* space is Hausdorff if and only if it is discrete.

Comment: So Hausdorff space has only /some/ points isolated, whereas a discrete space has /all/ points isolated?

Comment: @boreora: A Hausdorff space may have *no* isolated points; the space $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ are familiar examples of this.

Comment: Ok, I understand.